# Converted angular to ionic but it won't serve, give error that project is not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to convert an angular project to ionic, i've initialised and changed the config in angular.json, package.json and ionic.config.json project name matches.

The project name is simply "frontend", but when i now try to use ionic serve i'm getting this:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist.

I've checked everything i can think of and i don't see why it's not picking the project up, could do with a fresh pair of eyes please. I have listed each config file below, and i can't see any issue!

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "displayName": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.10",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture": "^5.37.3",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.8.4",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.8.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.28",
    "angular-flatpickr": "^3.6.6",
    "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^3.0.1",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.6.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "emoji-js": "^3.6.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionicons": "^5.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngb-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-paypal": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "ws": "^7.5.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1",
    "zxcvbn3": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.10",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "latest",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

**angular.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "frontend",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "frontend",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/core.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/structure.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/typography.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/display.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/padding.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/emoji.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "live": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.live.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "aws": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.aws.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/emoji.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "frontend:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "frontend:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve:production"
      

  }
      }
    },
    "ionic-cordova-build": {
      "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

**ionic.config.json:**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the `ionic serve` command use the app name as `app`, so that might be the problem.

Under the hood that command runs `ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100`, so you can try to map it into the `package.json` as a custom script with your app name.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "serve": "ng run frontend:serve --host=localhost --port=8100",
    ...,
  },
```

And then you can use it like `npm run serve`

Comment: If i run that command manually it works, for some reason won't work in the scripts in package.json, weird! But thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Quick question, how could i run it in an emulator with live reload? If i type ionic emulate ios --livereload it also doesn't work due to the above issue.

Comment: After cordova downloads everything it needs, you can run the command `ng run frontend:ionic-cordova-serve --host=localhost --port=8100 --platform=ios` (if you dont have the angular/cli globally you can run it with `npx ng run frontend:ionic-cordova-serve --host=localhost --port=8100 --platform=ios`

Comment: will that run it in an emulator though? looks like that would try to run it on a physical device. Also in this case how would you do live reload on the emulator? If i added --livereload to this command i believe it doesn't exist